# Aplicar expanded en hijo de columna dentro de singlechildscrollview

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, programación-móvil

Soy nuevo en flutter.
Por favor necesito hacer que mi ultimo Widget llamado CommonButton, se muestre en la parte inferior de la pantalla, el scroll lo agrego para que no aparezca el error de desborde de pixeles al pulsar sobre un Textfield y se levante el teclado, aquí mi código.
Comentar que estoy omitiendo las importaciones obviamente.
Intente envolver el CommonButton con un expanded pero me arroja error

W/MirrorManager(24153): this model don't Support

I/flutter (24153): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

I/flutter (24153): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():

I/flutter (24153): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

I/flutter (24153): When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is

I/flutter (24153): in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along
the vertical axis. Setting a

I/flutter (24153): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining

I/flutter (24153): space in the vertical direction.

I/flutter (24153): These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child

I/flutter (24153): cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

I/flutter (24153): Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible

I/flutter (24153): children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size

I/flutter (24153): themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and

I/flutter (24153): then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum

I/flutter (24153): constraints provided by the parent.

I/flutter (24153): If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():

I/flutter (24153):   https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer

I/flutter (24153):   http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html

I/flutter (24153): The affected RenderFlex is:

I/flutter (24153):   RenderFlex#2e328 relayoutBoundary=up18 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE(creator: Column ← Padding ← Padding ← DecoratedBox ← Container ← Column ← Padding ← DecoratedBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← ⋯, parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size), constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=374.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity), size: MISSING, direction: vertical, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: max, crossAxisAlignment: center, verticalDirection: down)

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const name = 'login_page';

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  TextEditingController usuarioController = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: BrandColor.cBlue,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: BrandColor.cBlue,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: BrandColor.cWhite,
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(lPaddingPage),
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                AssetData.loginImage,
                width: ResponsiveUI.pWidth(context, 0.5),
                height: ResponsiveUI.pHeight(context, 0.25),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: BrandColor.cMediumGrey,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(lCircularBorder),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(lCircularBorder),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  spacing10,
                  H4(
                    text: "Iniciar Sesión",
                  ),
                  spacing10,
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: BrandColor.cWhite,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(lCircularBorder),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(lCircularBorder),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(lPaddingPage),
                      child: Column(
                        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              CommonTextFormField(
                                hintText: "Ingresa usuario",
                                label: "Usuario",
                                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.person,
                                  color: BrandColor.cBlue,
                                ),
                                keyboardType: InputType.text,
                                controller: usuarioController,
                              ),
                              spacing16,
                              CommonTextFormFieldPassword(
                                controller: passwordController,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),

                          //expanded: Aqui el error!
                          //Expanded(
                          //child:
                          CommonButton(
                            text: "Iniciar Sesión",
                            backgroundColor: BrandColor.cOrange,
                            textColor: BrandColor.cWhite,
                            onPressed: () {
                              String domain =
                                  usuarioController.text.split("@").last;
                              BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context).add(
                                LoginInitSessionEvent(
                                  context: context,
                                  user: usuarioController.text,
                                  domain: domain,
                                  password: passwordController.text,
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                          //)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No puedes tener un expanded dentro de un column que está dentro de una vista con scroll. La vista con scroll le permite al column crecer infinitamente y el expande intenta tomar tanto espacio como sea posible; por tanto, tomará espacio infinito, lo cual no es posible.